# SwiftCharts- display one data point for Custom Units Scrollable graph

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swiftcharts

I would like to display one data point for Custom Units Scrollable graph (Custom Units Example). Is it possible to do it with this library?

I have looked into issues and the library to check and I only see [ChartAxisValue] array to create ChartAxisModel (i.e. xModel an yModel), no function to only add one ChartAxisValue for each. Would really appreciate your input. Here is an example of a function that I see w/ [ChartAxisValue]: `ChartAxisModel(axisValues: [ChartAxisValue], lineColor: UIColor, axisTitleLabel: ChartAxisLabel, labelsConflictSolver: ChartAxisLabelsConflictSolver, leadingPadding: ChartAxisPadding, trailingPadding: ChartAxisPadding, labelSpaceReservationMode: AxisLabelsSpaceReservationMode, clipContents: Bool)`

Would really appreciate your input.Thank you!

Link to Swift Charts: https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts